# HTML <script> to Javascript function confusion

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to convert this code I have in an html file to a javascript function so I can just call the javascript file from the html. If it is of any use, I am using that function to display/hide a dropdown menu(and it works fine already if I use it inside the html file).

```
<header>        
    <script>
    /* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(e) {
      if (!e.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
          if (myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            myDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
      }
    }
    </script> 
</header>
```

I tried just pasting the code above to the javascript file and calling that file from the html(using using the `<script src="../JavaScript/functions.js"></script>` However, it doesn't seem to work when I call it from the javascript file. The error I get when I click the DropDown menu is:
*Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick*

Comment: Where abouts are you referencing the `.js` file? In the `<head>` section of your page?

Comment: It's all JavaScript

Comment: Make sure the file is actually linked properly. And in case you actually have `<header>` and `<script>` in your js file, remove those. (and check the difference between `<header>` and `<head>`) edit: I just saw `"I tried just pasting the code above"`. Don't put HTML in a js file.

Comment: Does your log say anything by any chance?

Comment: Did you copy the `script` tags too?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] or as close as possible as you can see there is a lot missing from here. We need to see how you added the file to the header, we need to see how you attached the function to the button's onclick, etc...

Comment: The <script src="../JavaScript/functions.js"></script> work fines, but yes, I am using it on the header, which I think is the main problem. Is there any way I get to keep the function insider the header tag? when I have directly the function in the <script> tags it works fine

Comment: @Brolivar Please read my previous comment again. Then read it once more. Then do what it says. (and I really want to see that tutorial you're following, given that you're making seriously bad mistakes like this)

Comment: This is the tutorial. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click. As you can see, there you have the function inside the script tags, in the HTML file. I already got a js file with tons of functions, so I decided to take that functionality there (so yes in the js file there is no html code). I just want to take the code that there is inside the script tags to my js file. Thank you for answering.

Comment: So do it... create a js file and paste your js in there. Then in your html in the <head> tag (i.e. not the <header> tag) link your external script <script src="myscripts.js"></script>

Comment: Don't use w3schools. If you're still getting the error, chances are there's a syntax issue in your js file, or you've put the relevant function inside another function or something like that.